# Converting date to float days format for Matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I've got date in following format (get data from [here](http://api.huobi.com/staticmarket/btc_kline_005_json.js)):

```
20151204202500000
```

I want to use this date in Matplotlib candlesticks, so I need convert it to float days format.

Now I've got something like this:

```
    candlestick_data = []
    for line in data:
        # here I want to convert date
        newline = date, line[4], line[2], line[3], line[1]
        candlestick_data.append(newline)
        print(date)

    candlestick_ohlc(figure, candlestick_data)
```

But I can't figure out how to convert single string to float days format.
I don't even know how this format looks like...

I found the way to convert whole data file [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-date-stamps-matplotlib-tutorial/), but it wasn't too helpful for me.

Comment: You should take a look at the [candlesticks example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html) using dates as tuples instead of float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
import datetime
from matplotlib.finance import date2num

float_days = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'))
```

or the long version:

```
year = int(date_string[:4])
month = int(date_string[4:6])
day = int(date_string[6:8])
hour = int(date_string[8:10])
minute = int(date_string[10:12])
sec = int(date_string[12:14])
msec = int(date_string[14:] + '000')

float_days = date2num(datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec, msec))
```